# Function ignored by code, if written inside another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-2.7, tkinter

I have written a new Function1 (data_city) which is ignored if inserted inside another Function2 (write). I do not understand the problem. Previously I removed Function1 (data_city) and I copied / pasted the contents into IF of Function1 (data_city): in this way everything worked fine, everything ok. But if I create the (data_city) Function and call it inside the write Function, the data_city function is ignored and doesn't work. I'm starting out with Python, excuse me. Can you show me the code to solve the question?

I know the function is being ignored, because I don't have the same result as the second piece of code I am attaching (the one with with name_city, cursor.execute and results inside the IF of the write function). It should happen that texts are printed in the textbox thanks to text.insert (tk.END, f "{name_city} {'' .join (word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of ​​{surface}"). The data_city function, on the other hand, is used to fetch the entire row of the database corresponding to the item chosen in the combobox city.get

For the sake of completeness, usefulness and clarity of the question towards kind readers, I have posted the piece of code that gives me problems, the piece of code as it was in the past that worked, and also the complete code. Thanks a lot to those who will answer

```
def data_city():
    name_city = city.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TableExample WHERE Name_city=?',(name_city,))
    results = cursor.fetchone()


def write():

    results = data_city()

    if categoria.get() == "test1" and sottocategoria.get() == "test2":
   
        cursor.execute('SELECT Test1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
        word2 = cursor.fetchone()

        inhabitants = results[2]
        surface = results[3]

        text.delete(1.0,END)
        text.insert(tk.END, f"{name_city} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}")
```

Previously, the code with only one write function, and with the contents of the data_city function that I copied and pasted into the wriste function, was as follows. It worked fine, everything ok:

```
def write():
    if categoria.get() == "test1" and sottocategoria.get() == "test2":

        name_city = city.get()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TableExample WHERE Name_city=?',(name_city,))
        results = cursor.fetchone()

        cursor.execute('SELECT Test1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
        word2 = cursor.fetchone()

        inhabitants = results[2]
        surface = results[3]

        text.delete(1.0,END)
        text.insert(tk.END, f"{name_city} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}")
```

For reasons of clarity, usefulness and completeness of the application towards readers, I am attaching the entire code of the app for educational purposes:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

window=Tk()
window.title("aaaaa")
window.geometry("750x750")
window.configure(bg='#78c030')

con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/aaaa/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

### PULSANTI ###

def write():
    if categoria.get() == "test1" and sottocategoria.get() == "test 1.2":

        name_city = city.get()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TableExample WHERE Name_city=?',(name_city,))
        results = cursor.fetchone()

        cursor.execute('SELECT Test1 FROM TableExample2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
        word2 = cursor.fetchone()

        inhabitants = results[2]
        surface = results[3]

        text.delete(1.0,END)
        text.insert(tk.END, f"{name_city} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}")


button2 = Button(window, text="Button2", bg='white', command = write)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=5, y=330)

### TEXTBOX MULTILINE ###
text = Text(window,width=63,height=38)
text.pack()
text.place(x=180, y=24)

### CATEGORIA E SOTTO CATEGORIA ###
cat=StringVar()
sub_cat=StringVar()

def change_val(*args):
    if cat.get() == "test1":
        sottocategorias = ["test 1.1", "test 1.2", "test 1.3"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)
    else:
        sottocategorias = ["aaaa"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)

categorias=["test1", "test2", "test3"]
categoria=ttk.Combobox(window,value=categorias,
textvariable=cat,width=16)
categoria.place(x=5, y=25)
cat.set("Scegliere categoria")

sottocategorias=["aaaa"]
sottocategoria=ttk.Combobox(window,textvariable=sub_cat,
value=sottocategorias,width=16)
sottocategoria.place(x=5, y=55)

cat.trace("w",change_val) 

### COMBOBOX ###

### CAMPIONATO COMBOBOX ###
def combo_nation():
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Nation FROM TableExample')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

### SQUADRA COMBOBOX ###
def combo_city(event=None):
    val = nation.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT Name_city FROM Info WHERE TableExample = ?', (val,))
    result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    city['value'] = result
    city.current(0)
    return result

nation=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
nation['value'] = combo_campionati()
nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_squadre)
nation.place(x=5, y=150,height = 25, width = 180)

city=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
city.place(x=5, y=180, height = 25, width = 180)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure that your code appears formatted *exactly as you have it*. There are numerous indentation errors in the code you show here that would make it not run at all in Python, and it is not possible in general to guess how you actually have things nested.

Comment: Anyway, when you say that the function "is ignored", how do you know? When you say it "doesn't work", what is supposed to happen that doesn't happen? What exactly do you see when you run the program, and how exactly is that different from what you expect to see?

Comment: It appears that what you are asking about specifically is where you have `inhabitants = results[2]`; you are expecting this to use the `results` that were `return`ed from `data_city`. It does not work this way. Functions do not `return` variables; they return **values**, and if you want the caller to have a name for that value, then it has to assign its own name.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I know the function is being ignored, because I don't have the same result as the second piece of code I am attaching (the one with with name_city, cursor.execute and results inside the IF of the write function). It should happen that texts are printed in the textbox thanks to text.insert (tk.END, f "{name_city} {'' .join (word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of ​​{surface}"). When I run the program there are 4 comboboxes, a button and a large multiline texbox.

Comment: @Kark Knechtel The comment was too long. I divided it into two answers. The function of the program is to print some lines of text in the textbox, generated by text.insert (tk.END, f "{name_city} {'' .join (word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of ​​{surface} "). The text is taken from a database.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Can you show me how I need to change the code in the answer please? I'm just starting out with Python. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since `data_city()` returns a string, running it by itself won't do anything. You need to do `results = data_city()` in the `write()` function.

Your code should look like:

```
def data_city(name_city):
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TableExample WHERE Name_city=?',(name_city,))
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    return results

def write():
    name_city = city.get()
    results = data_city(name_city)

    if categoria.get() == "test1" and sottocategoria.get() == "test2":
        cursor.execute('SELECT Test1 FROM TableExample ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
        word2 = cursor.fetchone()

        inhabitants = results[2]
        surface = results[3]

        text.delete(1.0,END)
        text.insert(tk.END, f"{name_city} {''.join(word2)} {inhabitants} inhabitants on an area of {surface}")
```

Comment: Tried! I get an error (invalid syntax) in return = results. The "=" sign turns pink. Evidently this error was there even before. How can I correct? Thank you

Comment: `return = results` doesn't make sense so of course there's an error, I don't see that anywhere in your code so I'm guessing you added that to the end of `data_city()`. You don't have to change `data_city()` at all, you literally have to just replace `data_city()` with `results = data_city()` in the `write()` function. I never indicated that you had to add the nonsensical line `return = results` anywhere, so I'm not sure what prompted you to try that.

Comment: I had written return = results (for distraction without =) in the first gray square with the code at the top of the post. If you check there is. So my mistake. Anyway, I did what you asked me to do. Now the app starts, but when I click on the button, the text is not printed in the textbox. In the console I get the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable". There is something wrong

Comment: Consequently it is as if the function was not recognized, and ignored. But if you look at the second gray square of code, I put name_city, cursor.execute and results inside If (the data_city function doesn't exist yet): everything ok, everything works. Why does this work and with esults = data_city () (of course when you create the function) it doesn't work well?

Comment: Well, if `data_city` ends with `results = cursor.fetchone()` and then `return results`, then doing `results = data_city()`, and then something like `inhabitants = results[2]`, should work, just as if you put `data_city`'s contents in-line into your `write` function. I'm guessing that's where the error is. Maybe you can edit your updated code into the end of your question so I can see how you tried to fix it, and maybe I'll spot whatever the issue is.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the first gray square of code. I am currently using this code

Comment: The issue is that you removed `return results` from the end of `data_city`. I never said to change anything in that function, but you removed the part of it that actually returned data, so no wonder you're getting that error. You have to put `return results` back into it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I had made a mess. However I entered return results again, but the app does not start. It just doesn't open. It gives me an error: NameError: name 'name_city ' is not defined

Comment: Okay the issue is that you still have `text.insert(tk.END, f"{name_city}...` in your `write` function, and so since you only defined `name_city` in `data_city`, you'll get an error about it not being defined if you try to access it in `write`. You have to put `name_city = city.get()` into `write`. And maybe you could instead make `data_city` accept `name_city` as an argument, so that you don't have to run `name_city = city.get()` again in that function. I updated my answer with an example of this.

Comment: The app still doesn't open. I get the error: TypeError: data_city() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: You probably left in `def data_city():` instead of replacing it with `def data_city(name_city):` as I specified in my answer.

Comment: Aaaaaa yes. True. Forgive me. However now I have corrected. The text is printed in the texbox, but like this: <bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.ttk.Combobox object.! Combobox4 >> Blablabla. Blablabla. How can I remove the printing of <bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.ttk.Combobox object.! Combobox4?

Comment: That's really not related to the issue you asked this question about, so I suggest asking a new question about that specifically. The issue appears to be that you set the text of a text box to the `get` method of a Combobox object (like `city.get` instead of `city.get()`), or to the Combobox object itself (like `city`), instead of the result of that combobox's `get()` method (such as `city.get()`). That's just my guess, and I can't see where the issue in your code is, and since it seems like a common issue I'm sure others would be able to help easily if that was posted as a separate question.

Comment: However, I did not encounter this problem before modifying the code with your suggestion. The text came out correctly. If you look at the code of the second square above (the one without def data_city), the code was printed in a clear, simple and correct way. After your suggestions it comes out like this. It is not related to the problem I asked this question about because I was not having this problem. It was your code change that created this problem.

Comment: @GiovanniRusso I don't see how my small change could've caused that, and I can't find where the issue is.

Comment: Instead, yes. My code written in the third gray square above, i.e. the complete code, made the app work fine. I clicked on the Button and the text in the textbox was printed correctly. I'm sure of it because I did it repeatedly for several days. I also did this just before modifying the code with your suggestions. There was no problem. So it was your change that caused those <bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.ttk.Combobox object.! Combobox4? To print. They had NEVER printed before and the text printed correctly

Comment: Anyway no problem :) In part you solved my problem, indeed, no in part, but 80% solved it. Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. If nobody answers anymore, I will vote for you as the best answer. I'd like to ask you two things first though, please, since I'm just starting out with Python. Please try to explain it to me as easily and comprehensively as possible 1. Why (name_city) in def data_city? 2. Why did you insert (name_city) after data_city in the Write Function? Thank you

Comment: By putting `def data_city(name_city)`, we're defining `data_city` as a function that takes one argument, called `name_city`. I recommend taking a very basic Python tutorial, since functions and arguments are a fundamental part of the language. Also, the reason I put `data_city(name_city)` in the `write` function is because that's how you call a function while supplying an argument to it. Again, that's very very basic Python, and something you should have learned on day 1, so I really recommend looking at tutorials in order to understand what you're doing.